# Sails findOrCreate returns "record already exists" if running asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

Using sails.js, I have a service that is using .findOrCreate(...)

If this service is being called twice at the same time with the same data, it returns a "record already exists" error.

Is it a known issue? Any suggestions how to overcome it?

**Update:**

I'm using sails-mysql.
The query field is set as unique (which is why I'm getting this error, otherwise duplicates would have been created) and is also set as indexed (as suggested in the [Waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-methods.md))

**Update 2:**

Show.js:

```
tmdbId: {
  type: 'integer',
  unique: true,
  index: true
},
name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
slug: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},
seasons: {
  collection: 'season',
  via: 'show'
},
episodes: {
  collection: 'episode',
  via: 'show'
}
```

Service:

```
Show.findOrCreate({
  tmdbId: req.tmdbId
}, {
  tmdbId: req.tmdbId,
  name: req.showName,
  slug: Services.slug(req.showName)
}).exec(function (err, show) {
  if (err)
    return sails.log.error(err);
  Season.findOrCreate({
    show: show.id,
    number: req.season
  }).exec(function (err, season) {
    if (err)
      return sails.log.error(err);
    Episode.findOrCreate({
      show: show.id,
      season: season.id,
      number: req.episode,
      airDate: req.airDate
    }).exec(function (err, episode) {
      if (err)
        return sails.log.error(err);
      return res;
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you write down your query? Like `Model.findOrCreate({id:1},{name:'some name'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue with a postgres adapter and believe the cause is a race condition. This seems to be a known problem: [Waterline Docs: findOrCreate broken with high frequency calls #929](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/929)

`findOrCreate` doesn't appear to be atomic, so I think what happens is that the first call executes a `find` query which returns no results before executing the create operation. If the second call executes its `find` before the `create` of the first call has completed, it also return an empty result which triggers another `create`.

The problem occurs if the `create` data contains unique values. As the same data will be added twice because two `create` operations are executed, the second one fails because the unique value already exists in the database. In case there are no values which are marked as `unique` the result is a duplicate.

A way to address this problem is to catch the error and in the catch block do a `find` query because we know that the entry exists now, followed by any operations you intended to execute in the first place. Unfortunately though, this approach does become pretty ugly in your example, because of the nested `findOrCreate` calls which require their own catch blocks each.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Season` and `Episode` `findOrCreate` is not follow Sails convention. Try:

```
Show
    .findOrCreate({
      tmdbId: req.tmdbId
    }, {
      tmdbId: req.tmdbId,
      name: req.showName,
      slug: Services.slug(req.showName)
    })
    .exec(function (err, show) {
      if (err) return sails.log.error(err);

      Season
        .findOrCreate({
          show: show.id
        }, {
          show: show.id,
          number: req.season
        })
        .exec(function (err, season) {
          if (err) return sails.log.error(err);

          Episode
          .findOrCreate({
            show: show.id
          }, {
            show: show.id,
            season: season.id,
            number: req.episode,
            airDate: req.airDate
          })
          .exec(function (err, episode) {
            if (err) return sails.log.error(err);

            return res;
          })
        })
    })
```